# Group call implementation in Nodejs using Kurento

Tags: node.js, webrtc, kurento

How I can implement Kurento group call in nodejs?
I have used this npm example
https://github.com/thabung/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/release-5.1/kurento-group-call
But I am getting the error kurentoGroupCall.onStartNewCall is not a function.

any one has achieved this using nodejs?

Answer (score 3):

guys. I have a demo. (https://github.com/Cheng-Bin/kurento-group-call-node.git. Welcome to star/fork/issues.

Comment: I have implemented group call using your code. But I am facing audio quality issues with Kurento whenever three users join audio group call.